# allocate text value submitted by a form to a variable after clicking submit button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to store the text value submitted by clicking the submit button of a form, in a variable, so that I can use that variable for further querying the DB.

My Code:

```
<?
if($submit)
     {
       mysql_connect("localhost:3036","root","root");//database connection
       mysql_select_db("sync");
           $order = "INSERT INTO country (id,country) VALUES ('44','$submit')";
       $result = mysql_query($order);   
       if($result){
       echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
           } else{
       echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
}

?>

<html>
<title>form sumit</title>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?=$submit;?>"/>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

//In real case, the form has elements with radio button containing values from a DB QUERY,
I wanted to use the selected item from the form to process another DB query in the same page...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: where are u handling the form post .. i cant see it . Also you are using shorttags .. make sure your php.ini is configured for it

Answer (score 0):

Submitted form data automatically gets allocated to a variable ($_POST, in your case). If you want longer-term storage, consider using the $_SESSION variable, otherwise the submitted data is discarded upon script termination.

Please clarify your question, as I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here.

In a normal workflow, you would first check if your form has already been processed (see if $_POST has any data worth processing), then query the database for whatever data you need for your form, then render the actual form.

As promised, here's a hands-on sample:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['ajax']) {
    // This is a very trivial way of detecting ajax, but we don't need anything more complex here.
    $data = workYourSQLMagicHere(); //data should be filled with the new select's html code

    print_r(json_encode($data));
    die(); // Ajax done, stop here.
}

    /* Your current form generation magic here. */
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// This should probably go into a separate JS file.

$('#select1').change( function() {
    var url = ''; //Here we're accessing the page which originates the script. If you have a separate script, use that url here. Local only, single-origin policy does not allow cross-domain calls.
    var opts = { ajax: true };
    $.post(url, opts, function(data) {
        $('#select2').replaceWith( $.parseJSON(data) ); //Replace the second select box with return results
    });
});

</script>

<select id="select1"><?=$stuff;?></select>

<select id="select2"><?=$more_stuff;?></select>
```

Comment: the code I have given for is a sample code, but actually I was stucked for populating the second drop down list based on the selection of the first list where both the list display results from some DB query without hitting the submit button (I had to find the list of Departments and display only the courses offered in the selected department from database).... As I failed to do that I thought of doing the same thing in storing the value of submit button and then applying some db Query onthat....  Thank

Comment: There's two ways of doing that: either use the response data from $_POST to build the form step-by step, submitting the form for every step, or use JavaScript and AJAX to populate the second drop-down dynamically. You will need to use a supplementary script for that.

Comment: the second option is the one which I want to use,  I would like to request you to send me some sample tutorials and examples for the same... Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'll see if I can sketch up a more personal sample for you tonight, in the meantime, I'd recommend reviewing the W3C resource on the topic. You might be able to solve your problem on your own using this excellent AJAX tutorial. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Sorry for the delay, a bit pressed for time to elaborate now. More workable example tomorrow evening, awright?

Comment: ok , currently i am trying with the first approach (submitting at each step...)

Comment: Here's your sample. With some modification, you will be able to flesh it out in no time. Mind, this has not been tested in practice, so minor syntax errors might have crawled in.

Comment: thank you so much... I will go through the code now (I have never done AJAX before ) ...."

Comment: Understandable. There are several shortcuts to making jQuery ajax calls. $.post is one of them. There's also $.get (uses the GET method, rather than POST), $.load (never used this one), and the most flexible - $.ajax, which is actually what all the others are aliases of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<?php
$submit = $_POST['id'];

if($submit)
    {
        //your code is here 
            echo $submit;
    }

?>

<html>
<title>form sumit</title>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $submit; ?>"/>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```